# Customer journey with multiple users

Tags: info-visualisation, user-journey, journey-map

I'm looking if there are any examples of this as I want to draw a customer journey for a 2 sided marketplace where there's overlap between these 2 types of users. Think host/traveler for airbnb or rider/driver for lyft.

I can always design each individually and stack them to then call out where there are interesting moments/overlap between the two but was looking to see if a combo has been attempted before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can diagram these journeys in many different ways, and I have done this in the past although often the diagram becomes quite complex and the story gets lost sometimes.

There are a number of different approaches that I use, some of which might apply to your scenario/situation:

- Code the steps/stages in the journey in different colours for different users, to emphasise the difference in the number of steps or types of steps between different users visually.
- Create multiple lanes in the journey, one for each user, to emphasise the difference in the length of the journey or the relative complexity of each journey
- Create a journey for the primary actor/user along one axis, and then place secondary actor(s)/user(s) along the alternate axis for interactions with the primary actor/user

And you can probably combine them in different ways or formats if you need additional interactions or complexities for your journeys.